# How to keep track of the SCM revision in the build versions automatically?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version-control, build-process, visual-sourcesafe

I want to look at a production binary and know which revision in the SCM corresponds to that build. How it is possible? Can I accomplish that in Visual Studio using VSS?

Comment: Not "the" answer, but: does VSS support variable expansion like CVS/SVN? So you could put $VERSION$ or something alike in a header file to have it accessible by the code.

Comment: I also use SVN. Does this $VERSION$ tag works with Visual Studio + AnkhSVN? Or with TortoiseSVN?

Comment: It should work with any svn client. Here's some more info on it: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dave has answered:
"
You could put $VERSION$ or something alike in a header file to have it accessible by the code. It should work with any svn client. Here's some more info on it: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html
"

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking of any build created by any developer, then the answer is you can't, because even if you know the base revision the binary was created from, you don't know whether the developer had local modifications.

If you're talking about released software: Your binaries should have a version number attached and you should find a label/tag/branch with that version number in your repository. 
Of course, there's ways to automate this (keyword expansion come to mind, or an automated build script getting the version from the tag name), but in the end it all boils down to these three:

1. automated builds on a dedicated machine (preferably some GUI that you just throw a tag/label at)
2. version numbers in binaries
3. tags/labels/branches for released versions in the SCM.

Comment: I would like to know the base revision the binary was created from.

Comment: If you know any tool that does automated builds, and stamps it with the revision number, please tell.

Comment: Then keyword expansion (probably into a version resource) is the way to go.

Comment: For automated builds, basically all you need is a build script that you start passing a tag name. It's easy to hide that behind some HTML page. If you want to be fancy, provide some means to pick a tag, otherwise have the invoker paste it into an input field.